# Proving independence of two statistics (probably Basu's Theorem)

Tags: statistics, independence

Given that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d random variables with pdf $f(x)=\theta^{-1}e^{-\frac{x-a}{\theta}}I\{a<x<\infty\}$ for some constant $a$, where $I$ is the indicator function.

I want to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X_{(1)})$ and $X_{(1)}$ are independent. ($X_{(1)}$: smallest order statistic)

I'm trying to use Basu Theorem, I've shown that $X_{(1)}$ is complete, but I'm not able to show that $X_{(1)}$ is sufficient (tried to use factorization theorem but $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ shows up), and also $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X_{(1)})$ is ancillary. Can anyone provide some hint for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $\theta$ is known, then $X_{(1)}$ is sufficient for $a$. If not, the pair $(X_{(1)},\sum(X_i-X_{(1)}))$ is sufficient for $(a,\theta)$.

Comment: Can you show given $X_{(1)}=x$ that $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X_{(1)}) \sim \text{Gamma}(n-1,\theta)$ (shape,scale) and so is independent of $X_{(1)}$?